# How could fix my navigation bar background?

Tags: html, css

I cant find out why this is happening [view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdycB.png)
I am kind of new to HTML and CSS.
I tried messing a bit with the padding but it didn't helped me.

```css
/* Main website */

* {
  background-color: #232323;
  color: white;
}


/* Navigation bar */

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000f14;
}

.navbar li {
  float: left;
}

.navbar li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #000f14;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-placeholder">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar__container">
      <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="/index.html"></a><img src="/images/AquaTech navbar logo.png" alt="navbar__logo"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your problem with using **display: flex**. For the more informations about flex, you can check [the website](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

This code will be centered your navbar items.

```css
* {
    background-color: #232323;
    color: white;
  }


  /* Navigation bar */

  .navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000f14;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .navbar li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #000f14;
  }
```

```html
<div id="nav-placeholder">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar__container">
        <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
          <span class="bar"></span>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="/index.html"></a><img src="/images/AquaTech navbar logo.png" alt="navbar__logo"></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Heading ##you should learn flexbox

```css
    /* Main website */

    * {
        background-color: #232323;
        color: white;
      }
      
      
      /* Navigation bar */
      
      .navbar ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: #000f14;
      }
      ul{
        display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;}
      
      .navbar li {
        float: left;
      }
      
      .navbar li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #000f14;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/nav.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="nav-placeholder">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar__container">
          <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="/index.html"></a><img src="/images/AquaTech navbar logo.png" alt="navbar__logo"></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The logo seems not to be in line with the other menu items

Comment: sorry i don't have the logo thats why it seems not align

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that you have a typo:

```
<a href="/index.html">  
    </a> 
      <img src="/images/AquaTech navbar logo.png" alt="navbar__logo"></a>
```

You have got an extra closing tag before IMG tag.
It is best to use FLEX-BOX.
Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      /* Main website */

      * {
        background-color: #232323;
        color: white;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .navbar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        background: #000f14;
      }

      .navbar ul {
        background: #000f14;
        list-style-type: none;
        align-self: flex-end;
      }

      .navbar li {
        display: inline-block;
      }

      .navbar li a {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #000f14;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="nav-placeholder">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="/index.html">
            <img src="/images/AquaTech navbar logo.png" alt="navbar__logo"
          /></a>
          <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```